# iOS SwiftyJson encode JSON array into JSON

Tags: ios, json

I am trying to encode (from object to JSON string) the following JSON using SwiftyJSON in iOS:

```
{
    "item_list":[
        {
            "item_id":"id1", 
            "item_name":"name1"
        },
        {
            "item_id":"id2", 
            "item_name":"name2"
        }
    ]
}
```

I create the JSON object of each item through its own class. This is the code I used to generate the JSON object for an item:

```
public func getItemJson() -> JSON {
    var json:JSON = ["item_id":id, "item_name":name]
    return json
}
```

This is the code I used to trying to generate the overall JSON:

```
func getItemListJson() -> JSON {
    var list:[JSON] = []
    for item in itemList {
        list.append(item.getItemJson())
    }
    var json:JSON = ["item_list":list]      // This line contains error.
    return json 
}
```

However, I got a compiler error saying that "Type [JSON] does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'". What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The cause is that JSON is a struct and not an object. Using the .object method on then item's JSON resolves the error.

```
func getItemListJson() -> JSON {
    var list:[AnyObject] = []
    for item in itemList {
        list.append(item.getItemJson().object)
    }
    return JSON(["item_list":list]) 
}
```